# Unable to tigger elements inside the webui-popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I am working on a app dashboard, where I am trying to add a jquery calculator inside [webui-popover](http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/demo/). the calculator is working fine outside the popover but when it is inside the popover div it is not working. The plugin author said "This problem is caused by that the plugin stop the event bubbling",

I do not have much knowledge about Jquery or Javascript, If anyone can help me with this it will be nice. So, is there any way to make the calculator work inside popover element?.

Calculator Script taken from [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RzeRS/7/)

**Here is the codes**

```js
/* WEBUI SCRIPT*/
(function() {
  var settings = {
    trigger: 'click',
    title: '',
    width: 320,
    multi: true,
    closeable: false,
    style: '',
    delay: 300,
    padding: true
  };

  function initPopover() {
    var tableContent = $('#discalc').html(),
      tableSettings = {
        content: tableContent,
        width: 298
      };
    $('a.showdisclac').webuiPopover('destroy').webuiPopover($.extend({}, settings, tableSettings));
  }

  initPopover();
})();


/* CALCULATOR */

$("document").ready(function() {
  var key = null;

  $(document).on("click", ".clean", function() {
    $('.input').val("");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".Show", function() {
    var EText = $('#Result').val();
    if (EText != "0") {
      var val1 = EText;
      var ButtonVal = $(this);
      var val2 = ButtonVal.text();
      var Res = val1 + val2;
      $('#Result').val(Res);
    } else {
      $('#Result').val();
    }
  });

  $(function(e) {
    var interRes = null;
    var operator;
    $(document).on("click", ".operators", function(e) {
      var value1 = $('#Result').val();
      if (interRes != null) {
        var result = ApplyOperation(interRes, value1, operator);
        interRes = result;
      } else {
        interRes = value1;
      }
      operator = $(this).text();
      $('input').val("");
    });
    $(document).on("keypress", "#Result", function(e) {
      if ((e.keyCode == 61)) {
        var op = operator;
        var res;
        var value2 = $('#Result').val();
        if ((value2 != "")) {
          var data = value2.split("+");
          if (data.length > 2) res = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[data.length - 1], op);
          else res = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[1], op);
        } else {
          res = interRes;
        }
        $('#Result').val(res);
        interRes = null;
      } else if ((e.keyCode == 43) || (e.keyCode == 45) || (e.keyCode == 42) || (e.keyCode == 47)) {
        var value1 = $('#Result').val();
        var inter = (interRes != null);
        if (inter) {
          var op = operator;
          var data = value1.split("+");
          if (data.length > 2) {
            operator = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            result = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[data.length - 1], op);
            interRes = result;
          } else {
            operator = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            result = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[1], op);
            interRes = result;
          }
        } else {
          interRes = value1;
        }
        operator = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        $('.input').text("");
      }
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#Calculate", function(e) {
      var op = operator;
      var res;
      var value2 = $('#Result').val();
      if ((value2 != "")) {
        res = ApplyOperation(interRes, value2, op);
      } else {
        res = interRes;
      }
      $('#Result').val(res);
      interRes = null;
    });
  });

  function ApplyOperation(value1, value2, operator) {
    var res;
    switch (operator) {
      case "+":
        res = addition(value1, value2);
        break;
      case "-":
        res = subtraction(value1, value2);
        break;
      case "*":
        res = multiplication(value1, value2);
        break;
      case "/":
        res = division(value1, value2);
        break;
    }
    return res;
  }

  function addition(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var total = a + b;
    return total;
  }

  function subtraction(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var sub = a - b;

    return sub;
  }

  function multiplication(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var product = a * b;

    return product;
  }

  function division(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var divi = a / b;
    return divi;
  }

});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/dist/jquery.webui-popover.min.css"> .webui-popover-content {
  padding: 0;
}
.webui-popover {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.webui-popover.top>.arrow:after,
.webui-popover.top-right>.arrow:after,
.webui-popover.top-left>.arrow:after {
  border-top-color: #525252;
}
.discalc {
  display: none;
}
.disresform {
  background: #525252;
  padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -ms-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/dist/jquery.webui-popover.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="showdisclac" id="showdisclac" data-placement="auto-top" data-animation="pop" data-target="discalc">Discount</a>


<div id="discalc" class="discalc">
  <div class="disresform">
    <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>

    <input id="Result" class="input" value="0" />
    <div id="keys">
      <div id="FirstRow">
        <button id="ClearAll" type="reset" value="CE" class="clean">CE</button>
        <button id="Clear" type="reset" value="C" class="clean">C</button>
        <button id="Add" type="button" value="+" class="operators operand">+</button>
      </div>
      <div id="SecondRow">
        <button id="One" type="button" value="1" class="Show">1</button>
        <button id="Two" type="button" value="2" class="Show">2</button>
        <button id="Three" type="button" value="3" class="Show">3</button>
        <button id="Sub" type="button" value="-" class="operators operand">-</button>
      </div>
      <div id="ThirdRow">
        <button id="Four" type="button" value="4" class="Show">4</button>
        <button id="Five" type="button" value="5" class="Show">5</button>
        <button id="six" type="button" value="6" class="Show">6</button>
        <button id="Mul" type="button" value="*" class="operators operand">*</button>
      </div>
      <div id="FourthRow">
        <button id="Seven" type="button" value="7" class="Show">7</button>
        <button id="Eight" type="button" value="8" class="Show">8</button>
        <button id="Nine" type="button" value="9" class="Show">9</button>
        <button id="Divide" type="button" value="/" class="operators operand">/</button>
      </div>
      <div id="FifthRow">
        <button id="Zero" type="button" value="0" class="Show">0</button>
        <button id="Dot" type="button" value="." class="Show">.</button>
        <button id="Calculate" type="button" value="=" class="operand">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dismissible:false`

```js
/* WEBUI SCRIPT*/
(function() {
  var settings = {
    trigger: 'click',
    title: '',
    width: 320,
    multi: true,
    closeable: false,
    style: '',
    delay: 300,
    padding: true,
    dismissible:false
  };

  function initPopover() {
    var tableContent = $('#discalc').html(),
      tableSettings = {
        content: tableContent,
        width: 298
      };
    $('a.showdisclac').webuiPopover('destroy').webuiPopover($.extend({}, settings, tableSettings));
  }

  initPopover();
})();


/* CALCULATOR */

$("document").ready(function() {
  var key = null;

  $(document).on("click", ".clean", function() {
    $('.input').val("");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".Show", function() {
    var EText = $('#Result').val();
    if (EText != "0") {
      var val1 = EText;
      var ButtonVal = $(this);
      var val2 = ButtonVal.text();
      var Res = val1 + val2;
      $('#Result').val(Res);
    } else {
      $('#Result').val();
    }
  });

  $(function(e) {
    var interRes = null;
    var operator;
    $(document).on("click", ".operators", function(e) {
      var value1 = $('#Result').val();
      if (interRes != null) {
        var result = ApplyOperation(interRes, value1, operator);
        interRes = result;
      } else {
        interRes = value1;
      }
      operator = $(this).text();
      $('input').val("");
    });
    $(document).on("keypress", "#Result", function(e) {
      if ((e.keyCode == 61)) {
        var op = operator;
        var res;
        var value2 = $('#Result').val();
        if ((value2 != "")) {
          var data = value2.split("+");
          if (data.length > 2) res = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[data.length - 1], op);
          else res = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[1], op);
        } else {
          res = interRes;
        }
        $('#Result').val(res);
        interRes = null;
      } else if ((e.keyCode == 43) || (e.keyCode == 45) || (e.keyCode == 42) || (e.keyCode == 47)) {
        var value1 = $('#Result').val();
        var inter = (interRes != null);
        if (inter) {
          var op = operator;
          var data = value1.split("+");
          if (data.length > 2) {
            operator = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            result = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[data.length - 1], op);
            interRes = result;
          } else {
            operator = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            result = ApplyOperation(interRes, data[1], op);
            interRes = result;
          }
        } else {
          interRes = value1;
        }
        operator = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        $('.input').text("");
      }
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#Calculate", function(e) {
      var op = operator;
      var res;
      var value2 = $('#Result').val();
      if ((value2 != "")) {
        res = ApplyOperation(interRes, value2, op);
      } else {
        res = interRes;
      }
      $('#Result').val(res);
      interRes = null;
    });
  });

  function ApplyOperation(value1, value2, operator) {
    var res;
    switch (operator) {
      case "+":
        res = addition(value1, value2);
        break;
      case "-":
        res = subtraction(value1, value2);
        break;
      case "*":
        res = multiplication(value1, value2);
        break;
      case "/":
        res = division(value1, value2);
        break;
    }
    return res;
  }

  function addition(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var total = a + b;
    return total;
  }

  function subtraction(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var sub = a - b;

    return sub;
  }

  function multiplication(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var product = a * b;

    return product;
  }

  function division(first, second) {
    var a = parseFloat(first);
    var b = parseFloat(second);
    var divi = a / b;
    return divi;
  }

});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/dist/jquery.webui-popover.min.css"> .webui-popover-content {
  padding: 0;
}
.webui-popover {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.webui-popover.top>.arrow:after,
.webui-popover.top-right>.arrow:after,
.webui-popover.top-left>.arrow:after {
  border-top-color: #525252;
}
.discalc {
  display: none;
}
.disresform {
  background: #525252;
  padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -ms-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/dist/jquery.webui-popover.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="showdisclac" id="showdisclac" data-placement="auto-top" data-animation="pop" data-target="discalc">Discount</a>


<div id="discalc" class="discalc">
  <div class="disresform">
    <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>

    <input id="Result" class="input" value="0" />
    <div id="keys">
      <div id="FirstRow">
        <button id="ClearAll" type="reset" value="CE" class="clean">CE</button>
        <button id="Clear" type="reset" value="C" class="clean">C</button>
        <button id="Add" type="button" value="+" class="operators operand">+</button>
      </div>
      <div id="SecondRow">
        <button id="One" type="button" value="1" class="Show">1</button>
        <button id="Two" type="button" value="2" class="Show">2</button>
        <button id="Three" type="button" value="3" class="Show">3</button>
        <button id="Sub" type="button" value="-" class="operators operand">-</button>
      </div>
      <div id="ThirdRow">
        <button id="Four" type="button" value="4" class="Show">4</button>
        <button id="Five" type="button" value="5" class="Show">5</button>
        <button id="six" type="button" value="6" class="Show">6</button>
        <button id="Mul" type="button" value="*" class="operators operand">*</button>
      </div>
      <div id="FourthRow">
        <button id="Seven" type="button" value="7" class="Show">7</button>
        <button id="Eight" type="button" value="8" class="Show">8</button>
        <button id="Nine" type="button" value="9" class="Show">9</button>
        <button id="Divide" type="button" value="/" class="operators operand">/</button>
      </div>
      <div id="FifthRow">
        <button id="Zero" type="button" value="0" class="Show">0</button>
        <button id="Dot" type="button" value="." class="Show">.</button>
        <button id="Calculate" type="button" value="=" class="operand">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```